# Layout issue with ie7

Tags: html, css, alignment

It looks like my [website](http://goo.gl/GfQ53) does not look good in ie7 (see screenshot below)
My menu supposed to be horizontal is vertical, and facebook & twitter buttons are above each other and not next to each other.
Is there a way to fix these 2 issues?
Many thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/aKPgt/

In a nutshell, change:

```
display:inline-block;
```

to

```
display:inline;
```

and add:

```
float:right;
```

Just remember, you need to REVERSE the order of your menu items in your unordered list, since
you're floating RIGHT instead of LEFT.

Answer (score 0):

"My menu supposed to be horizontal is vertical"

This type of IE7 problem would typically occur if you were trying to make a set of `<li>` or `<div>` tags take `display:inline-block` -- which works in IE8 and current versions of the other browsers.

The problem is, IE7 respects `display:inline-block`, but only on elements that are, by default, inline such as `<span>` or `<a>`. So it just keeps them as blocks, and so they stack vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I would try applying `float: left;` to both `#nav > li` and `#nav a`.

That should fix the vertical stack issue with IE7.